# Why do semantically different words produce similar embeddings?

Tags: word-embeddings, semantic-similarity

I am comparing words in [HuggingFace web UI](https://huggingface.co/intfloat/e5-small-v2) using `e5-small-v2`, one of the best vector embedding models:

[image]

Assuming that the scores are in the range from 0 to 1, how come all the scores are so high? In fact, I was not able to produce any example with a score below 0.7. Is there something basic I am missing about vector embeddings?

Answer (score 2):

I explored this very problem in one of my medium posts.[Why are Cosine similarities almost always positive](https://vaibhavgarg1982.medium.com/why-are-cosine-similarities-of-text-embeddings-almost-always-positive-6bd31eaee4d5).

Quoting from that:

> In other words, the cosine similarity has a positive contribution if
> the corresponding dimensions in the vector are either both pointing in
> the positive direction, or both in the negative direction. Since the
> max pool moves some dimensions in the positive direction, it is
> statistically imperative in a large dimensional space to have a net
> positive bias.

If this causes issues for processes downstream, you can train a transformation matrix that multiplies each of the two vectors. This is done such that the cosine distances of dissimilar vectors get larger to span the full -1 to +1 range. The matrix would have to be trained on a subset of data that closely resembles your intended application.